# Automation: How to run some program on multiple windows 7 PCs?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-7, automation, psexec

I have an program which I need to run on multiple PCs (>100) all in same domain and share the same user and password.
  If I run a program manually, it opens a console windows where I can see the logs running. I can remote desktop and still be able to see the console windows open and logs running. It helps in debugging as I can see whats going on. Issue is I want to avoid running it manually on all PCs.

I have following requirement
a. It should be able to run program on multiple pcs remotely
b. program should open in foreground where console logs can be seen.
c. launching PC should launch program on PC1 and then  (without wait for the program to finish on PC1) it should launch the program on PC2 and so on.

1. I explored STAF it needs to be installed on all stations. Its heavyweight, needs complex configuration.
2. I explored power shell , it needs to be enabled on all stations and also probably (read somewhere) has issue with running tasks in foreground.
3. psexec can run the program but it does it in background, if I use -i option I need to give session id so only it will show the console for a specific remote desktop session. Another major issue with -i is that it will interactive so it waits until the program exits.

   4. Looked a paexe, its simillar to psexe and doesn't solve the issue I am facing with psexe.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hmm. `psexec \\computer -i -d c:\full\path\program.exe` is said to not wait for finish, and `-i` without extra parameter will launch the software on console. Should you need it, specify `-x` and get your app over a logon screen.

Comment: -i -d works in non-waiting mode but doesn't bring the application on the foreground.so effectively its like -d only. i tried psexec \\computer -i -d notepad.exe (and also my program)

Comment: Hmm, maybe then deploy the software via group policy computer-based script (copy only), then create a schedules task to start that software at specific time on all PCs?

Comment: psexe -i -s -d \\remote cmd works fine and shows the gui, works also if user logged in on the remote pc, but doesn't work when working on remote pc via remote desktop or user is not logged in.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a server, you can put the program on the server and create a shortcut to it (assuming the program is small/simple enough to run on a network share).

You can use One-Click to deploy the programs, and give each of your users a link.

You can change the program into a website for central access.

You can use group policy to deploy the program when a user logs in, assuming you can create a .msi file from it.

Comment: Thanks oppassum, I updated my question to be more specific and to stress more on execution rather installation. please see if you know the answer.